# OAuth or SSL for Web API

Tags: ssl, oauth

I'm getting confused. I have an API that will be accessed by a client via port. And I am thinking of using SSL Self signed server certificate for authentication and security, but I read about OAuth which is being used for authentication. What's better to use between the two or is it better to use both?

Answer (score 1):

These are two different things.

SSL (which is now properly known as TLS) will let you encrypt data in transit, to avoid anyone in the middle from seeing the contents. If you are using a "real" certificate, that is, one signed by a recognized Certificate Authority, then you can also verify the certificate represents the entity it says it represents. (A self-signed certificate will not get you that benefit.)

OAuth is an authentication mechanism. It will let you authenticate a remote client (which is usually a user or a service acting on behalf of a user). You can perform this authentication over an encrypted tunnel provided by TLS, but it is a separate action from encrypting the traffic between the endpoints.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but what I'm getting here is that it's better to use both. Right ?

Comment: One more thing, forgot to ask. The client will integrate the api (URI) to their own project, so does that imply that if I use OAuth, the client will not be able to integrate my api ? So, should I use a server certificate only ? Thanks.

Comment: Using TLS is increasingly viewed as appropriate or even necessary, so sure, you should use it.  I am not familiar enough with OAuth specifically to say much more about that, though.

Comment: Okay. I see. Thank you very much !